# Location of Application's info.plist

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, plist, project

I'm reorganising a project's structure and I would like to move my application's info.plist file to a nested folder within my project. Is this a bad idea? So far as I can see there are no relative paths within it, so as long as my project knows where it is things would appear to be OK, but am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you place it in a sub directory, as long as you set the correct path in the build settings of the target.

The key is called `Info.plist File` in the build settings.